# Type mismatch when removing empty rows macro

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a macro to remove all empty rows from all sheets. The macro runs but I get a "Type mismatch" error. Why do I get this error?
Thanks!

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()

Dim I As Integer, row As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    For row = 10 To 1 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(row, 4).Value = "" Then ws.rows(row).Delete
    Next row
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Upon which line? You say also that the "Macro Runs" does it delete any rows before throwing the error?

Comment: It runs just fine for me and does not throw any errors. Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: Do any of the cells you're checking in ColD contain errors?

Comment: Is this all of the code that you try to run, or have you stripped it down? You have declared `I As Integer`, what have you used that for? This could be the culprit depending on what you used it for.

Comment: @JNevill Yes it does delete rows and then it throws the error.

Comment: @PeterT It was line 6: If ws.Cells(row,4).... The code from Vityata did helped. thanks for the support

Comment: @JvdV I was working on other code and didn't delete that line. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the `.Value = ""` and the value of the cell is an error (it returns Type Mismatch). This is a good work around:

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()

    Dim i As Long, row As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For row = 10 To 1 Step -1
            If IsError(ws.Cells(row, 4)) Then
                ws.Rows(row).Delete
            ElseIf ws.Cells(row, 4).Value = "" Then
                ws.Rows(row).Delete
            End If
        Next row
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Vityata, this code helped me without throwing the error!